# zuul and not latin symbols in url params

Tags: java, spring-boot, url-encoding, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have zuul gateway with spring boot using by @EnableZuulProxy

When I use the not latin parameter in url I get error in gateway application:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
>   at > org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:479) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]

in log traces I see turning of my parameter from ?lastName=dfg%D1%8Bsdfd into ?lastName=dfgÑsdfd

As I understand this is the result of conversion to iso-8859-1 encoding.I tried to use spring-boot-starter-undertow instead of tomcat, but it not have effect.

I have seen discussions of this problem in old posts, but it claims that the problem has been fixed in the current version of spring-cloud

Answer (score 0):

It was property in application yml:
    zuul:
      forceOriginalQueryStringEncoding: true